# Grab Values Within a Dictionary in a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I may have not written the best of codes, but let's say I have a dictionary within a dictionary which output looks like this:

```
print node
> {
>  0: {'NODE': 'CLOUDY', 'GATE': 'EQUAL', 'PROB': 0.5}, 
>  1: {'NODE': 'RAIN', 'CPT_1': 0.2, 'CPT_0': 0.8, 'GATE': 'OR', 'PROB': 0.5, 'PNODE_0': 'Cloudy'}, 
>  2: {'NODE': 'SPRINKLER', 'CPT_1': 0.9, 'CPT_0': 0.5, 'GATE': 'OR', 'PROB': 0.7, 'PNODE_0': 'Cloudy'}, 
>  3: {'NODE': 'WETGRASS', 'CPT_3': 0.01, 'CPT_2': 0.1, 'CPT_1': 0.1, 'CPT_0': 1.0, 'GATE': 'OR', 'PROB': 0.5, 'PNODE_0': 'Rain', 'PNODE_1': 'Sprinkler'}
> }
```

I want to see the final result of:

```
print string
> ['CLOUDY', 'RAIN', 'SPRINKLER', 'WETGRASS']
```

So far, I have written this to get an output exactly as the one above.

```
string = "["
for value in xrange (0, len(node)):
    string += "'" + node[value].get("NODE") + "', "
string = string[:-2]
string += "]"
print string
```

I was wrapping my head around extracting all values from a dictionary within a dictionary that has a key of "NODE". Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the values from the dict:

```
print([d["NODE"] for d in node.values()])
['CLOUDY', 'RAIN', 'SPRINKLER', 'WETGRASS']
```

If the key might not be in all dicts just use `in` to check first:

```
print([d["NODE"] for d in node.values() if "NODE" in d])
```

`node.values()` is going to give you all the dicts:

```
[{'NODE': 'CLOUDY', 'GATE': 'EQUAL', 'PROB': 0.5}, {'NODE': 'RAIN', 'CPT_1': 0.2, 'CPT_0': 0.8, 'GATE': 'OR', 'PROB': 0.5, 'PNODE_0': 'Cloudy'}, {'NODE': 'SPRINKLER', 'CPT_1': 0.9, 'CPT_0': 0.5, 'GATE': 'OR', 'PROB': 0.7, 'PNODE_0': 'Cloudy'}, {'NODE': 'WETGRASS', 'CPT_3': 0.01, 'CPT_1': 0.1, 'CPT_0': 1.0, 'CPT_2': 0.1, 'GATE': 'OR', 'PROB': 0.5, 'PNODE_0': 'Rain', 'PNODE_1': 'Sprinkler'}]
```

So you just extract from each.

If you actually want to form a string that looks like a list:

```
 s = "[{}]".format(",".join([d["NODE"] for d in node.values() if "NODE" in d]))
```

Or simple:

```
print(str([d["NODE"] for d in node.values() if "NODE" in d]))
```

Comment: Oh gosh. Why didn't I think of that? I completely forgot about the 'in'. Thanks so much, @Padraic.

Comment: @jetmas, no worries, do you actually want a list or a string?

Comment: I just need a string that looks like a list. That actually works perfect for what I need. Again, thanks a bunch.